# Como faço para salvar matrizes no disco rígido?

Tags: matlab

Como faço para salvar no disco rígido matrizes criadas no MATLAB?

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: Não entendi os negativos, será porque não entendo de MATLAB? Tem tanta porcaria que recebe positivos, essa pode não estar na melhor forma mas está longe de ser tão ruim assim.

Comment: Concordo @bigown falta sim mostrar o esforço até o momento do AP, mas é sua primeira pergunta. Acostumar-se ao modelo é algo que ocorre com o tempo, e no início basta ajudar a entender o modelo, mas muita gente não entende isso

Comment: "tanta porcaria que recebe positivos" ---> +1 pra isso

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão de que é uma pergunta perfeitamente válida. Poderia até ser melhor elaborada (qual foi a dificuldade, o que foi tentado), mas é uma duvida razoável. Pode realmente ser que quem negativou tenha uma razão, mas tem chance de ser aqueles "bots" de fila" de costume.

Comment: Sinceramente não acho válida do modo como esta escrita. Eu não sabia como fazer, mas fiz uma busca simples no Google e o segundo resultado era a documentação oficial com a resposta. Mas existem muitas perguntas piores que recebem upvote e esta com uma edição simples se tornaria perfeitamente válida.

Answer (score 3):

Para salvar uma variável (qualquer uma, que eu saiba), em um arquivo, basta utilizar o comando `save`.

Este comando possui várias opções que controlam o formato da escrita da variável, e compatibilidade do formato com outras versões do Matlab.

O site à seguir possui mais informações e foi encontrado utilizando uma busca simples no Google:

[Save workspace variables to file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)